# Confusion regarding a library of Digital Signal Controller

Tags: filters, filter-design, dsp-core, butterworth, embedded-systems

I'll be using a NXP DSC with 56800Ex core and my aim is to implement a Elliptic IIR Filter in it.

The User Reference Manual of the 'General Digital Filters Library' (which is available [here](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/user-guides/56800Ex_GDFLIB.pdf)) has functions to implement IIR Filters.

> [image: Page 3-19]

But on page 3-19 shown above, it says

> The filter coefficients are calculated using Butterworth approximation.

- Does this mean that we can only use Butterworth Filter? Also, as per my knowledge, we have to give the coefficients and therefore other filters can also be implemented.
- So what exactly does the function do?
- Can I implement a Elliptic filter using this function or not? If not, then what should I do use Elliptic filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are refering to only implements an order-1 filter. There is another function for order-2 filter.

If you want to implement an order-3 filter, you will have to split it in an order-1 filter and an order-2 filter. There are many ways to do it, but cascading the filters, as we would do in the analog world, is a good solution, albeit not optimal IIRC.

As to your original question, since the function refers to an order-1 IIR filter, an order-1 Elliptic or Butterworth, will have the same coefficients if you design them with the same cut-off frequency.

However, starting with order 2 or more, the coefficients will not be the same.

Comment: So is the IIR4 function capable of implementing the elliptic filter or not?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it is such a good idea to use a function that implements an order-4 IIR filter directly. Especially since you use integers, quantization effects could come back to haunt you.

You can implement an elliptic filter using a combination of order-2 IIR and order-1 IIR. 

Say your filter is an order-3 elliptic IIR filter. Split in 2 cascaded-filter. You will have an order-2 filter and an order-1 filter. Use the appropriate function for each filter.

I would have written the same thing had your filter been a Butterworth, or Chebyshev. The IIR type doesn't matter.